# check if each value of array are equal

Tags: postgresql, optimization, array

I try to get **d.id** only if all rows with same id have same **pday**:

```
with dif_zero as (d.id, 
date_part('day', p.docdate)::text pday
from sh_billing.dogovor d 
join sh_billing.pays p on p.dogovor_id = d.id and p.is_actual
)
select id
from 
dif_zero 
group by id
having sum(char_sal_dif) = 0 
and avg(pday::int) =  (array_agg(pday))[1]::int 
and avg(pday::int) =  (array_agg(pday))[2]::int -- and so on...
```

Maby there is other way (more simple) to get to know if all elements in array equals to one another?

Or I can use window functioin in subquery, and after take only rows with value = 1.

```
select id, count(id) over(partition by id) one_day
```

Wich way is better? Or maby there is other way to do it more corrent?

Comment: Why cast `date_part` to `text` just to convert it back to a number later? Your query also misses the `char_sal_dif` column

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for giving my attention to this! It's just historical reason, forgot to delete casting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that all days are the same, just compare the min and max. If they are the same, then all values are the same as well.

```
with dif_zero as (
  select d.id, 
         date_part('day', p.docdate)::int pday
  from sh_billing.dogovor d 
   join sh_billing.pays p on p.dogovor_id = d.id and p.is_actual
)
select id
from 
dif_zero 
group by id
having sum(char_sal_dif) = 0 -- where does char_sal_dif come from? 
   and min(pday) = max(pday)
```

A more costly (=slower) but maybe easier to understand way, is to compare the count with the count of distinct values:

```
having count(*) = count(distinct pday)`
```

Comment: Thanks for min max comparison! It's quite elegant!